# How to make Spring Cloud Contract reset WireMock before or after each test

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, wiremock

We are writing a Spring Boot application and use the Cloud Contract WireMock support to stub a backing service. Our test class is annotated like so:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 0)
public class Tests...
```

This works fine except for one thing: We found out that Spring Cloud does not seem to reset WireMock, in particular delete stubs, in between tests so that tests are not isolated properly. Of course, you can accomplish this yourself with a `@Before` method containing a `reset()`, but we wonder whether this is intentional. Is there an option that we have overlooked or an additional annotation one has to use?

After all, it is not possible to define stubs in a `@BeforeClass` method that would be gone if a reset would always be performed, so we wonder what speaks against doing it out of the box?

Answer (score 8):

Configure Spring Boot property:

```
wiremock:
  reset-mappings-after-each-test: true
```

ref: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/commit/67119e62f6b30da56b06aade87ec3ba61de7fd24

Answer (score 2):

I ended up injecting WireMockServer and running `wireMockServer.resetAll()` in @BeforeEach.

Comment: Of course, we did the same thing, my question was more like: Is there an out-of-the-box solution? Anyway, the Spring Contract team acknowledged in the meantime that this is a bug and is fixed with 2.1.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT and 2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.

Answer (score 1):

The WireMock server can be reset at any time, removing all stub mappings and deleting the request log. If you’re using either of the JUnit rules this will happen automatically at the start of every test case. However you can do it yourself via a call to `WireMock.reset()` in Java or sending a POST request with an empty body to `http://<host>:<port>/__admin/reset.`

To reset just the stub mappings leaving the request log intact send a DELETE to `http://<host>:<port>/__admin/mappings.`

Hope this is useful.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Because we are using the WireMock support of Spring Cloud Contract, we do not use the WireMockRule. My question is: Why does Cloud Contract not reset WireMock before each test automatically? Is this intentional, and if so why? Or is it a involuntary omission, aka bug?